# Need a help on Quartz scheduler; scheduler stopped scheduling new jobs

Tags: java, quartz

I am using Quartz 2.2.0 for my project. It's JSP/servlets application with a HANA database. There is a background job where I am using Quartz. The application running smoothly till we are getting this error. Need help with this. Thank you in advance.

```
Couldnt store job: SAP DBTech JDBC: [274]: inserted value too large for column: Failed in "IS_DURABLE" column with the value 'false' 
_ OpenSQLExceptionCategories: [NON_TRANSIENT, COLUMN_UNKNOWN] 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1117) __ 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$2.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1061) __ 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$45.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3705) __ 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:245) __ 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3701) __ 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1057) __ 
org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:916) __ 
org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249) __
```

Comment: Error is with the HANA database insert query." Failed in "IS_DURABLE" column with the value 'false' ".Can you check data type of IS_DURABLE field during insert vs db datatype ?

Comment: yes, you are correct the problem with the database column, where initially it was varchar(1) and storing 0 or 1 now it's changed to true and false. I am wondering why this has happened.

Comment: You can change the data field type like varchar(5) or make sure input 0/1 from a code base input.